System sound play on some sound ID and not on some others
I have the below code. Here is the status.
Sound 1304 will be played on both MacBook Pro macOS 14.2.1 Xcode preview mode and iPhone 15 Pro iOS 17.4.1.
Both sound 1211 and 1016 will be played on macOS only. It is not played on iPhone. As I remembered, 1211 and 1016 were okay to play on iPhone before.
func playOkBeep() {
//    let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016 //SMSSent
//    let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1211 //TouchTone
    let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1304 //SystemSoundPreview alarm
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)
}

